# Como listar as variáveis definidas dentro de um escopo em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variáveis

Como faço para saber/listar quais variáveis já foram definidas dentro de um escopo, seja global ou local?

Por exemplo se eu definir  `var x, y, z = 10`, o resultado de um possível comando de listar as variáveis já definidas deveria ser algo como um `array` com seus nomes: `["x", "y", "z"]`.

É possível fazer isso em JavaScript?

No R, por exemplo, esse comando seria `ls()` e retornaria um vetor de *strings* com os nomes das variáveis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso não é possível em JavaScript, pois os objetos onde as variáveis ficam armazenadas (*environment records*) não estão disponíveis para o usuário da linguagem, exceto no caso do objeto global. Mas mesmo nesse caso, listar as propriedades do objeto global irá incluir todas as variáveis globais, não somente as que você criou. Por exemplo:

```
var a = 10;
for(i in window) {
    if(window.hasOwnProperty(i)) console.log(i)
}
```

A saída incluirá sua variável `a`, mas também inclui `document`, `localStorage`, `name`, etc.

---

Você pode contornar parcialmente esse problema passando adiante o objeto `arguments` de uma função para a outra. Por exemplo:

```
function soma(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

function subtrai(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}

function somaOuSubtrai(a, b) {
    // Transforma os argumentos de objeto para array, esperada pelo apply.
    // Não é 100% necessário, mas garante compatibilidade com implementações antigas
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    if(a >= b) {
        return subtrai.apply(null, args);
    } else {
        return soma.apply(null, args);
    }
}

somaOuSubtrai(1,3); // 4
somaOuSubtrai(3,1); // 2
```

Outra alternativa é empacotar suas variáveis como propriedades de um objeto (um *namespace*), como foi sugerido pelo @Sergio. No final pode ser que você acabe usando uma combinação dessas estratégias.

Comment: Estranho isso. Como fazer, por exemplo, para aplicar uma função em um conjunto de diversas variáveis? Você vai ter que escrever todas manualmente no script?

Comment: Sim, você tem de listá-las uma por uma na hora de aplicar a função. Uma exceção é se quiser passar adiante os argumentos recebidos por uma função, neste caso é possível aplicar outra função diretamente ao objeto `arguments` da primeira.

Comment: @CarlosCinelli Adicionei um exemplo do que é possível fazer com os argumentos, talvez seja próximo do que você está precisando.

Comment: @bfavarreto, valeu!

Answer (score 6):

Como o @bfavareto também referiu isso não é possível em Javascript. Porém, se planear bem o seu código usando um espaço reservado pode fazer essa verificação. Contudo, variáveis defenidas dentro de funções nao são acessíveis a escopos exteriores.

```
var namespace = {
    minhafuncao1: function () {

    },
    minhavariavel1: 100
}

for (variable in namespace) {
    console.log(variable);
}
```

Dá:

```
minhafuncao1 
minhavariavel1
```

Comment: Isso pode ser interessante mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

**Sim** e *não*. **Não** em quase todas as situações. **Sim**, mas apenas de forma limitada, se você quiser verificar o alcance global. Veja o seguinte exemplo:

```
var a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;

for ( var i in window ) 
{
    console.log(i, typeof window[i], window[i]);
}
```

Que gera, entre *150+* outras coisas, o seguinte:

```
getInterface function getInterface()
i string i // <- Veja aqui!
c number 3
b number 2
a number 1 // <- Outro...
_firebug object Object firebug=1.4.5 element=div#_firebugConsole
"Firebug command line does not support '$0'"
"Firebug command line does not support '$1'"
_FirebugCommandLine object Object
hasDuplicate boolean false
```

Por isso, **é possível listar algumas variáveis ​​no escopo atual, mas não é confiável, eficiente, ou facilmente acessíveis**.

A melhor pergunta é por que você quer saber o que as variáveis ​​estão no escopo?

<sub>[**Resposta original em inglês**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2052434/1608936)</sub>